# How to make a shortcut for running laravel project automatically in windows

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, terminal

How to make a shortcut that is doubled clicked and it run the laravel project automatically.

---

**Manual process**
what we do to run a Laravel project:
First of all we open the terminal(mac) or cmd (windows), then in the terminal we type the following command in order to reach the location where the laravel project is.

```
cd <your project location>
```

After accessing the project folder, we type the following command to run the project.

```
Php artisan serve
```

I want the whole process is done by a single shortcut, is it possible?, if yes, kindly help me up.

Comment: create a `bat` script to run project automatically

Comment: do you mean an alias for **php artisan serve** 

What I suggest is to use hosts it is better and you don't need to access each time into u folder and run the cmd.. if you are working under windows Laragon did that automatically and create for you the host so you access to by the name of your folder (projet.test) , mac Valet do the same

Comment: Adding to what @Scorpion shared, you also have to have in mind that if you don't use any web server like Apache or Nginx or others, if you do a change to your code, you sometimes have to stop the process and run it again... that would be not desired... using web servers, no need to do so... That is why we mostly use Docker (at least for developing purposes), way easier to work with in an environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this by making shorcut, with your commands that you want to trigger.

For more help you can click on the below link:
https://www.howtogeek.com/277403/how-to-run-command-prompt-commands-from-a-windows-shortcut/

steps:

1. Create a shortcut by right-clicking anywhere in File Explorer or your desktop and choosing New > Shortcut.
2. In the Create Shortcut window, type your command using the following syntax:

"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k yourcommand

The first part (the part in quotes) just calls cmd.exe to open the Command Prompt. The switch /k tells Command Prompt to issue the command that follows, and then stay open so that you can view results or type followup commands. You can also use the /c switch instead /k (use only one of the switches) if you want the Command Prompt window to close after issuing the command. And of course, the yourcommand part is the actual command you want to run.

"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k cd yourProjectFolder & php artisan serve

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include the most part of the given link ?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30420572)

Answer (score 0):

In windows, like said before, you can create a `bat` script. Open notepad, write something like the following and save as "something.bat".

```
@echo off
Rem Change Directory to your project
cd C:\<your project directory>
Rem Run Artisan Command
php artisan serve
```

Then, doble click your `bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way, you could refer to this package called Laravel Valet (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/valet), this is a package that you could install to your project folder and all laravel projects in that folder can be run automatically by entering the [project name].test in the browser once Laravel Valet is configured and started. For example, if you have a project in the folder where valet is installed, you could enter demo.test in your browser and then the project will be loaded automatically

Answer (score 0):

Go and right click on your mouse or touch pad, make a shortcut, and then add  command
commmand "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k cd rootfolder & php artisan serve